# Error: Cannot file channel name in Tcl

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to open a file for read, asking input from user from a Tk file open dialog box, but facing an Error “`cannot file channel named`”
Here is my code.
Can you let me know the issue with below code?

```
proc load_input_entries {} {
    global  sa sd sb sc

    set types {
        {{Text Files}   {.txt}        }
        {{CSV Files}    {.csv}        }
        {{All Files}    *             }
    }

    set fp [tk_getOpenFile -parent . \
           -title "Select File" \
           -filetypes $types -multiple true \
           -initialdir "/simulation/safe/ip/work" ]

    if {[file exists $fp]} {
        set stuff [read $fp]
        set lines [split $stuff "\n"]
        set sa [lindex $lines 0]
        set sb [lindex $lines 1]
        set sc [lindex $lines 2]
        set sd [lindex $lines 3]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`tk_getOpenFile` gives you the file *name*. You still have to open the file to be able to read it. Try

```
set filename [tk_getOpenFile ...
if {[file exists $filename]} {
    set fp [open $filename]
    ...
```

If you get a problem like this, it's often useful to temporarily insert a `puts` command to see what the value of your variable is. If you had done that, you would have seen that it had a file name instead of a file handle.